# Directive Two Way Binding with ng-repeat is not binding back to the model

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In the below code, I've bound the array data `$scope.data.arraydata` to the custom section `mysection`.

And, for each arraydata I am binding the textbox with some keys for that array.

e.g. var1, var2

Also on adding multiple sections, the above is working fine.

But when I try to get the scope data with the below, the `arraydata` inside `$scope.data` is not binding back with the values `var1` and `var2`

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('form')).scope().data
```

e.g. Expected Output (on adding 2 sections)

```
{
   "test":"Single Data",
   "arraydata":[
      [
         {
            "var1":"aaa",
            "var2":"bbb"
         }
      ],
      [
         {
            "var1":"ccc",
            "var2":"ddd"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

            $scope.data = {

                "test": "Single Data",
                "arraydata": []
            }

            $scope.addSection = function () {

                $scope.data.arraydata.push([]);

            }

            $scope.addSection();
        });

        app.directive('mysection', function () {

            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    arrdata: "=?"
                },
                template: $("#SectionTemplate").html()
            }

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body id="form" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div>
        {{data}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ arrdata }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <mysection ng-repeat="arrdata in data.arraydata" ng-model="arrdata"></mysection>
    </div>

    <button type="button" ng-click="addSection()">Add Section</button>
</body>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="SectionTemplate">
        <div style="border: solid 1px red">
            {{ arrdata }}
            <input type="text" ng-model="arrdata.var1" />
            <input type="text" ng-model="arrdata.var2" />
        </div>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see two things in the code:

1. NgModel is not relevant here. Instead, the directive is expecting `arrdata` input binding attribute.
2. The `push` method is pusing an array, and the directive is expecting an object.

Example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

            $scope.data = {

                "test": "Single Data",
                "arraydata": []
            }

            $scope.addSection = function () {

                $scope.data.arraydata.push({});

            }

            $scope.addSection();
        });

        app.directive('mysection', function () {

            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    arrdata: "=?"
                },
                template: $("#SectionTemplate").html()
            }

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body id="form" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div>
        {{data}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ arrdata }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <mysection ng-repeat="arrdata in data.arraydata" arrdata="arrdata"></mysection>
    </div>

    <button type="button" ng-click="addSection()">Add Section</button>
</body>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="SectionTemplate">
        <div style="border: solid 1px red">
            {{ arrdata }}
            <input type="text" ng-model="arrdata.var1" />
            <input type="text" ng-model="arrdata.var2" />
        </div>
    </script>
```